# Updating code from openCV to openCV2

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to update some code from openCV to openCV2 in python. The original code is as follows:

```
self.capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
cv.SetCaptureProperty( self.capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160 );
cv.SetCaptureProperty( self.capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120 );
```

The code that I wrote for openCV2 is this:

```
self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.VideoCapture.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160 );
cv2.VideoCapture.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120 );
```

However this does not work I'm getting an error that says:

> cv2.VideoCapture.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160 );
>   AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'set'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one. It will work.

```
self.capture.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160)
```

Comment: Same here: global name error on 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH'

Comment: Ok I actually got this working but is this still using the old openCV library since your using cv2.cv.....

Comment: It is not using the old library because of that, `cv2.cv` is just a namespace for constants which translate from the original `CV_SOMETHING` to python's variant `cv.SOMETHING`.

Answer (score 16):

i came across this same issue, was able to get it work with:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160);
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't actually set the frame dimensions it captures.

Answer (score 13):

It seems that **CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC** and other such similar properties are deprecated in your installed version of Opencv, to solve the problem for example this property ,Change it to `cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` and similarly others too. Works good for me on Opencv 3.1

Comment: Thank you - I keep encountering this issue, but forget the solution - appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

I removed `.cv.CV_`, and it worked.

Change:

```
cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT
```

to:

```
cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on the *instance* returned by your initial call, not the class

```
self.capture.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160)
```

Comment: I see what you mean now, I'm looking at the documentation for openCV I didn't understand that initially, however, it is throwing another error: NameError: global name 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH' is not defined

Comment: You don't put the cv-prefix in your migrated code, as you do in the original.

Comment: I still get the same global name error on 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH'

Comment: I highly doubt that. Because the error-message should be "AttributeError: module cv has no attribute CV_CAP....'. So I guess that's not really in the part of the code you edited/show.

Comment: Ok so here is the exact code: self.capture.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160) This throws a global name error, but this self.capture.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160) throws attribute error, like you said it should

Comment: So it is a different global error! It should mention 'cv'. You need to be precise about this stuff. The global name error is cv2. Does `cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` work? Maybe after you have imported `import cv2.cv`.

Comment: I'm using this import: import cv2 and this cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH This is working now

Comment: This whole this is woefully hard to figure out - I tried giving the docs & failed miserably.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was constructed using a combination of proposed answers/ tutorials

Using cv2 - change the Frame resolution from Video captured via webcam

```
import cv2
import time

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

print "Frame default resolution: (" + str(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)) + "; " + str(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)) + ")"

#set Frame resolution to 1280; 720
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
print "Frame resolution set to: (" + str(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)) + "; " + str(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)) + ")"

r, frame = cam.read()

print('Resolution: ' + str(frame.shape[0]) + ' x ' + str(frame.shape[1]))
```

[Screenshot: default resolution and changed resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkE4I.png)

Comment: Could you post those answers and tutorials that you've used?