# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cv' (similar topic didn't help)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using python-OpenCV version 4.4 and when running just a basic code block:

```
import cv2

camera_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fps = 30
size = int(camera_capture.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),\
        int(camera_capture.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('MyOutputVid.avi', cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('I','4','2','0'),
fps, size)
```

I get `AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cv'`
I understand there has been a transition from OpenCV to OpenCV2 but how
the imports were affected ?

I found similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640911/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-cv) but removing second `cv2` from the code didn't help in my case. It just threw another error `AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH'`

How can I use the attributes ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51853018/11667949

Comment: @ShivamJha  How does ^ this help ? I don't have problem with installation.

Comment: You could test a couple of combinations i guess. It probably should be " cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT ". See some more examples here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076403/updating-code-from-opencv-to-opencv2

Comment: @Grebtsew  I've tried that one already. Got the error `cv2 has no attribute CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT`

Comment: Okej, It seems to be working for me on python 3.8, cv2 4.4.0.42. Tried reinstalling it?

Comment: You should also replace cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(...) with cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this code seems to be working. Hopefully doing what you want. Works on windows 10, python3 3.8.6 64-bit, opencv-python 4.4.0.42.

```
import cv2

camera_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fps = 30
size = int(camera_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),\
        int(camera_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

vidwrite = cv2.VideoWriter('testvideo.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('I','4','2','0'), fps, 
           size,True)


# Write and show recording
while camera_capture.isOpened():

        _, frame =  camera_capture.read()
        vidwrite.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow("showlive", frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

If you still have issues with *CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT*, I would suggest reinstalling opencv. Some functions in OpenCV is not supported for 32-bit version of python3, might be worth checking aswell. An alternative ofcourse is to instead use `height, width, _ = frame.shape` see *frame* in the code above.

Comment: So the main issue was `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` vs `CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH`  during the transition from cv1 to cv2 they apparently changed names of the methods as well. I'm learning from a book that was published 2016 and uses cv2 but some of the methods the book uses remained unchanged and throw an error.